# How do i define guild on Visual studio code? Discord.js

Tags: visual-studio-code, discord, discord.js

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const BOTCLIENT = new Discord.Client();
const Token = '...2vXOGsiI';
const Prefix = '-';

BOTCLIENT.on('ready', () => {
    BOTCLIENT.user.setActivity("Prefix = '-', Made by Zachary#9293"); 
        });

BOTCLIENT.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('online');
})
BOTCLIENT.on('message', message=>{
let args = message.content.substring(Prefix.length).split(" ");

   switch(args[0]){
    case 'Commands':
    message.channel.send("My commands are here: 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/...aBbo6k0/edit?usp=sharing'" )
    break;
    case 'Invite':
    message.channel.send("My invite is 'https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=...382&scope=BOT%20BOIIIIIIIIII&permissions=8'")
    break;
    case 'CreateChannel':
        guildMember.roles.add(['123456789012345678', '098765432109876543']);
            break;


   }  
})
BOTCLIENT.login(Token);
```

Is my code, but i get the error "Define guild" I have googled and googled but cannot find out how to define guild! somebody please help.

Here's The error I'm getting:

```
ReferenceError: guild is not defined
    at Client.<anonymous> (c:\Users\OKBOO\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\index.js:34:9)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (c:\Users\OKBOO\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (c:\Users\OKBOO\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (c:\Users\OKBOO\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (c:\Users\OKBOO\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (c:\Users\OKBOO\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (c:\Users\OKBOO\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (c:\Users\OKBOO\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:800:20)
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the full error (such as 'ReferenceError: guild is not defined' or something). Also, please change your Discord token. You just leaked it.

Comment: Error is "ReferenceError: guild is not defined"

Comment: Could you please include the full error (including the stack trace)?

Comment: You need to reset your token, you just leaked it, please store your tokens in separate files

Comment: You only need 1 of each event, get rid of the second `ready` event

Comment: I am currently aware of the leaking of my token, as 3 servers have been destroyed (uh oh) But i am confused still at how to define it?

Comment: is it like let guild = message.guild?

Comment: Also how do i store my token in a different file?

Comment: The stack trace is to long, all though i will send pastebin

Comment: https://pastebin.com/5YcEweMz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at this code I suspect that its something to do with:

```js
        guildMember.roles.add(['123456789012345678', '098765432109876543']);
```

I dont see guildmember getting defined anywhere.

---

you could try define it with `let guildMember = message.member`

you can define 'guild' with `let guild = message.guild`

---

Also as Syntle said you dont need two ready events, just put them both into one

```js
BOTCLIENT.on('ready', () => {
    BOTCLIENT.user.setActivity("Prefix = '-', Made by Zachary#9293"); 
    console.log('online');
        });
```

---

As for storing your token in a different file you can do it by doing this:

```js
// index.js
const config = require("./config.js")
const token = config.token
```

```js
// config.js
module.exports = {
      token: "REALTOK3N"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Unkwn is right `guildMember`is not defined. 
If you're trying to add roles to the person who send the command, replace it by `message.member`

The whole ine would be : `message.member.roles.add(['123456789012345678', '098765432109876543']);`